# Is Schema.org's LocalBusiness just allowed for local business?

Tags: schema.org, ecommerce

I have created an online shop for bikes. They do not have an offline (brick & mortal) shop.

Can I use the  Schema.org type `Bikestore` (e.g. in Microdata: `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Bikestore"`) or is it just for local businesses?

Answer (score 2):

`https://schema.org/BikeStore` (with a **capital** S) is defined in the following hierarchies:

> Thing > Place > LocalBusiness > Store > BikeStore 
>   Thing > Organization > LocalBusiness > Store > BikeStore

The definition of [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) says:

> A **particular physical business or branch** of an organization. Examples of LocalBusiness include a restaurant, a particular branch of a restaurant chain, a branch of a bank, a medical practice, a club, a bowling alley, etc.

So, no, it would not be appropriate to use that particular `itemtype` for an online-only store.

Other Microsoft data from schema.org might be appropriate though.